# Create Folders and rules in exchange server 2003

Tags: exchange-server, webdav, exchange-server-2003

I would like to know How to Create Folders and rules in exchange server 2003 as i am using webdav code in c#. I have tried with few examples but not able to get it.

Comment: This should help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563302(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reference but i am using exchange 2003 as your reference link address exchange 2010.

Answer (score 0):

To create a folder, just issue a MKCOL request on the target url.

This is a small sample (withouth any error handling or so):

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://exchangeserver/exchange/username/NewFolder");
request.Method = "MKCOL";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.GetResponse();
```

Regarding the rules. There is no good way to do this using WebDAV. You should check another technology, like Redemption. It can be used from .NET and offers the functionality you need.

Outlook Redemption: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/